# Exim не использует search-домен при подключении к postgres

Tags: postgresql, search, exim, domain

Пытаюсь из exim-а подключаться к postgres и дёргать запросы. В конфиге exim-а указаны параметры подключения - host/db/user/password, но эта странная программа не умеет определять ip postgres по его короткому имени (использовать search-домен указанный в resolv.conf).

```
# cat /etc/resolv.conf
search company.com
nameserver 10.20.25.1

# ping postgres
PING postgres.company.com (10.20.25.151) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from postgres.company.com (10.20.25.151): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.140 ms

# exim -be
> ${lookup pgsql {servers=postgres/db/user/password; SELECT 1} {true}{false}}

Failed: lookup of "servers=postgres/db/user/password; SELECT 1" gave DEFER: PGSQL connection failed:
could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Name or service not known

> ${lookup pgsql {servers=postgres.company.com/db/user/password; SELECT 1} {true}{false}}
true
```

tcpdump показывает, что exim пытается определять имя "postgres" как полное

```
22:09:47.985371 IP 10.20.25.94.58569 > 10.20.25.1.53: 49358+ A? postgres. (26)
22:09:47.985483 IP 10.20.25.94.58569 > 10.20.25.1.53: 23255+ AAAA? postgres. (26)
22:09:47.985639 IP 10.20.25.1.53 > 10.20.25.94.58569: 49358 NXDomain 0/1/0 (101)
22:09:47.985696 IP 10.20.25.1.53 > 10.20.25.94.58569: 23255 NXDomain 0/1/0 (101)
```

Знает кто-нибудь как научить эту странную программу использовать подстановку search-домена из resolv.conf ?